# How to get the local attribute values of Xml through java

Tags: java, xml

I tried some scenario's but unable to get the attribute values of the following xml through java

```
enter code here

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Rules>
    <Rule ID="1" Name="Ms 45 MD -&gt; BS 1 ON @ 300 secs" Valid="1">
            <Triggers Count="1">
            <Trigger ID="1" TriggerType="Device" DeviceID="4" DeviceIndex="1" GroupingType="AND" Condition="eq" Validation="true" Duration="2147483647">true</Trigger>
            </Triggers>
            <Results Count="1">
                    <Result ID="1" ResultType="DeviceResult" DeviceID="1" DeviceIndex="1" PreDelay="300" Validation="true">true</Result>
            </Results>
    </Rule>
    </Rules>
```

i need values of the following attributes
- Triggers count, Trigger ID,TriggerType,DeviceID and data between Triggers tag
- Results Count, Result ID, ResultType, DeviceID, preDelay and data between Result tag in a loop

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Trigger")) {
item = new Item();
System.out.println("RuleInfo");
Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();
while (attributes.hasNext()) {
Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("ID")) {
System.out.println("Trigger ID ="+attribute.getValue());}
if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("TriggerType")) {
System.out.println("Trigger Type="+attribute.getValue());}
if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("DeviceID")) {
System.out.println("Device ID="+attribute.getValue());}}

Comment: You have many XML parsers to choose for this task such as xerces.apache.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how print the the "Count" value.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse("put_the_path_to_your_file_here");
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList rules = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Rule");
for (int i = 0; i < rules.getLength(); ++i) {
  Element rule = (Element) rules.item(i);
  Element triggers = (Element) rule.getElementsByTagName("Triggers").item(0);
  int count = Integer.parseInt(triggers.getAttribute("Count"));
  System.out.println("Count=" + count);
}
```

You need to specify the path to your file in the call to `.parse` on the 3rd line.

Also note that for this code to compile you'll have to import stuff like:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
```

Comment: thanks, your code is working fine for me, but unable to get Rule ID, Name, Valid

Comment: @mahi for Rule ID use:
System.out.println("ID: " + rule.getAttribute("ID")); for Rule name use:       System.out.println("Name: " + rule.getAttribute("Name"));